# Generate relations between tables Oracle with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I Have a database that was handed to me in my job, in ".dmp" format, i imported it to my work space, and my mission is to understand it and  make some changes in it, my problem is it contains a lot of tables and i want to understand the relation between each table.

My question is, is there a way to show the relations between all the tables?  is there a way to generate a model that shows them all? something i need to install?

I'm using Oracle 10g Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible using tool. 
**SQL DEVELOPER** is oracle provided free tool using which you can generate model which will show you relations between tables graphically.
Details procedure you may find it int the below link.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-may/o34sqldev-2193423.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what i was looking for !

Comment: @zenami Happy to hear that. Feel free to ask if you face any issue. Thanks for vote..

Comment: the only problem i am facing right now, is i have about 300 tables in my database, so when i generate the model, it looks like a big mess, not understandable, so many associations, what i want is a way to structure the model, give it a nice looking understandable model,  without having to do it manually for all the tables and relations.

Comment: One suggestion is, do not bring all tables once with all stuff like foreign key . Bring object wise tables separately, for example only booking / sales related tables. Understand those first go for rest set. Like this approach can be followed.